# Gamma matrices and a vector

Tags: supersymmetry, spinors

Let $\theta$ be an anticommuting Majorana spinor and $A^\mu$ a vector. Is there an easy way to show then that $\bar{\theta} \gamma^{\mu} \gamma_5 \theta \bar{\theta} \gamma^{\nu} \gamma_5 \theta A_{\mu} A_{\nu} = (\bar{\theta} \theta)^2 A_{\mu}^2$? 
I couldn't think of anything better than just computing all those products directly, but I guess there is some nice way. 
The question originated when I tried to expand $\exp(2V)$, where $V$ is in Wess-Zumino gauge.

Comment: Hint: If you have something like $\sum_{\mu \nu} A^{\mu \nu} B_{\mu \nu}$ with $B$ symmetric, replace $A^{\mu \nu}$ by $A^{\mu \nu}_{sym} + A^{\mu \nu}_{antisymmetric}$.

Comment: @AHusain the antisymmetric part will vanish, and with symmetric part I would like to use the identity ${\gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{\nu}} = 2 \eta^{\mu \nu}, but for that I need gamma matrices be near each other. I had an idea of using Fierz identity, but it doesn't look like it helps: \gamma^{\mu} \gamma_5 is one of the basis matrices in Fierz decomposition. Am I missing something?